# How can i join the count of points into polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two layer (point and polygon) which are kept in the same geodatabase. I want to find how many points exist in one polygon, and I googled my problem, but I could not understand how to solve my problem exactly (with this **[answer](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30779)**)

I want to perform a density analysis based on the counts of the points in each polygon, but I cannot find how many points are contained in each polygon.

Comment: There are [many solutions posted on this site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=point+polygon+arcgis+count): take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to GIS SE.

You can use the [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) tool in ArcGIS at any license level to match points to polygons. Use the "ONE TO MANY" option if some points belong to multiple polygons.

You can follow this analysis with [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) to report the point counts in table format.

If you have QGIS you can use the [Points in Polygon](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-spatial-analysis-points-in.html) tool.